# OleDB Criteria Mismatch

Tags: sql, .net, database, vb.net

This is my last working code. It saves data from a burst of string. Using `,` as a delimiter, I added them into an array. Even if it has null values, it saves nothing on the DB.

```
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tblGPSRoutes" & _
                                    "(UTCTime,Status,Latitude,NSIndicator,Longitude,EWIndicator," & _
                                    "SpeedOverGround,CourseOverGround,UTCDate,MagneticVariation,EWIndicatorB,Mode,Cheksum)" & _
                                    " VALUES " & _
                                    "(@utctime,@status," & _
                                    "@lat,@nsindicator," & _
                                    "@long,@ewindicator," & _
                                    "@sog,@cog,@utcdate,@magnet," & _
                                    "@ewindicatorb,@mode,@checksum)"

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con) 'myconnection - is your connection object'
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@utctime", txt(1))
            .AddWithValue("@status", txt(2))
            .AddWithValue("@lat", txt(3))
            .AddWithValue("@nsindicator", txt(4))
            .AddWithValue("@long", txt(5))
            .AddWithValue("@ewindicator", txt(6))
            .AddWithValue("@sog", txt(7))
            .AddWithValue("@cog", txt(8))
            .AddWithValue("@utcdate", txt(9))
            .AddWithValue("@magnet", txt(10))
            .AddWithValue("@ewindicatorb", txt(11))     
            .AddWithValue("@mode", txt(12))             
            .AddWithValue("@checksum", txt(13))
End With
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

---

This is my edited code because I need to parse the `latlon` datas.. this is where the title appears.. can you see what's wrong?

```
    Dim la As Double = Double.Parse(txt(3).Substring(0, 2)) + Double.Parse(txt(3).Substring(2)) / 60.0
    Dim lo As Double = Double.Parse(txt(5).Substring(0, 3)) + Double.Parse(txt(5).Substring(3)) / 60.0

Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tblGPSRoutes" & _
                                    "(UTCTime,Status,Latitude,NSIndicator,Longitude,EWIndicator," & _
                                    "SpeedOverGround,CourseOverGround,UTCDate)" & _
                                    " VALUES " & _
                                    "(@utctime,@status," & _
                                    "@lat,@nsindicator," & _
                                    "@long,@ewindicator," & _
                                    "@sog,@cog,@utcdate)"

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con) 'myconnection - is your connection object'
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@utctime", txt(1))
            .AddWithValue("@status", txt(2))

            If txt(3) IsNot Nothing Then
                .AddWithValue("@lat", la)
            Else
                .AddWithValue("@lat", "No Data") 'is this possible?'
            End If

            .AddWithValue("@nsindicator", txt(4))

            If txt(5) IsNot Nothing Then
                .AddWithValue("@long", lo)
            Else
                .AddWithValue("@long", "No Data")
            End If

            .AddWithValue("@ewindicator", txt(6))
            .AddWithValue("@sog", txt(7))
            .AddWithValue("@cog", txt(8))
            .AddWithValue("@utcdate", txt(9))
End With
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'error here..
    End Using
```

---

I was thinking that maybe because I *removed* the number of data's to be inserted on a pre-made access database throws it? As you can see, I cut off the number of fields in **code2** because there had been some error on the strings sent to me, and they are not that important, so I removed the code where they will be *inserted* in the DB, though their fields are still there. That was my first assumption (but I think not really)

Anyway, I did not test it yesterday so I thought about it. My GPS module hardly get signals so I can't test thoroughly, (*strings were from it, so if it does not work, so am I*)

Comment: what is the data type of column Latitude? if it non-string then it is impossible instead use DBNull.Value() over "No Data".

Comment: Number>Double.. but I don't think the database causes the problem, because it was working fine at first.

Comment: If the datatype is numeric then the DBMS will reject the non-numeric value.  Instead use DBNull.Value() over "No Data".

Comment: `DBNull.Value` is an error, tried `0` though. and I think, its working fine now. thank you for the idea!

Comment: may the column is not accepting null value. However, you do have the good grasp!